# How to get bucket details using boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

Below is the code I am using to get details for all the buckets present in, but I am getting some errors:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection, OrdinaryCallingFormat
from boto.s3.key import Key

host = 'hostname'
port = 9022
accessKeyId = 'accessKeyId'
secretKey = 'secretKey'

conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key_id=accessKeyId,
                  aws_secret_access_key=secretKey,
                  host=host,
                  port=port,
                  is_secure=False,
                  calling_format='boto.s3.connection.ProtocolIndependentOrdinaryCallingFormat')

rs = conn.get_all_buckets()
len(rs)
```

Error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list-bucket.py", line 17, in <module>
    rs = conn.get_all_buckets()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 447                                                                 , in get_all_buckets
    response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:Error xmlns:n                                                                 s2="http://www.emc.com/cos/"><Code>1033</Code><Message>Unable to retrieve                                                                  the secret key for the specified user.</Message></ns2:Error>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use "import boto3; client = boto3.client("s3"); client.list_buckets()"?

Comment: **Side-comment:** `boto` is now outdated. It is recommended that you use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).

Comment: time to upgrade to Python3 as well

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, I will start it with boto3, but yesterday  I also figured this out. I was using wrong port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using boto3

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print (bucket.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong port that's why I was getting error, below are the correct ports:

```
S3 Protocol API

ports 9020 and 9021 (http and https)
```